# A simple json request returns a strange string rather than json itself

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to return a simple json in Go. This is a web app and here's a part of a handler:

```
func JsonTest1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  test1 := "something1"
  test2 := 456
  j1 := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`
    {
      data: {
        "test1": %s,
        "test2": %d
      }
    }
  `, test1, test2))



  j2, _ := json.Marshal(&j1)
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  w.Write(j2)
 }
```

When I'm doing a request via curl, I receive something like:

```
  CiAgICB7CiAgICAgIGRhdGE6IHsKICAgICAgICAicmVkaXJlY3RfdXJsIjogdGVzdF9yZWRpcl91cmwxLAogICAgICAgICJtZXNzYWdlIjogdGVzdCBtc2cgMQogICAgICB9CiAgICB9CiAg
```

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: It's a base64 encoded string:  {
      data: {
        "redirect_url": test_redir_url1,
        "message": test msg 1
      }
    }

Comment: @Kurohige - my task is to return json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you JSON-encode a `[]byte`, it will be rendered as a base64-encoded string, the most effective way to represent an arbitrary byte slice/array in JSON (the only real alternative being `"field": [7, 129, 13, 48, ...]` and so on). In your code, however, you're doing a couple of unusual things that may not be what's intended:

- You're manually creating a JSON-ish string using `Sprintf`, then trying to JSON-encode your JSON. `json.Marshal` is for taking some arbitrary Go value and rendering it as JSON.
- Your manually-created JSON is invalid; you have a string field value that's unquoted.

What you want is probably one of these options:

```
// Manually-created *valid* JSON
func JsonTest1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    test1 := "something1"
    test2 := 456
    // %q instead of %s gives us a quoted string:
    j1 := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`
    {
      data: {
        "test1": %q,
        "test2": %d
      }
    }
  `, test1, test2))

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(j1)
}

// JSON created with json.Marshal
func JsonTest2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    test1 := "something1"
    test2 := 456
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "data": map[string]interface{}{
            "test1": test1,
            "test2": test2,
        },
    }
    j1, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(j1)
}
```

Comment: I did, two different ways.

Comment: I would note that using `fmt.Sprintf()` is not advisable: it doesn't know about JSON syntax and it's easy to generate invalid JSON that way (especially if string values are substituted in).

Comment: Definitely agree but to each their own. `Sprintf` is a legitimate way to generate JSON, but not one I would choose in 99% of situations.

Comment: yes, the json is invalid: "Unexpected token d in JSON at position 13"

Comment: @Pappani not sure what you mean - the JSON produced by the above code would be valid, and neither the code in this answer nor quoted in your question ever tries to *umarshal* any JSON, so the error you commented isn't possible. If you're running into a new issue you're unable to resolve, open a new question.